# I want the ability to cut from a locked sheet without unlocking

Tags: excel

Currently I have a shared excel sheet that has multiple people using it. I am using ranges to allow edits to certain cells by the people that need to edit those cells. I want to give the ability for one person to cut the entire row without having to unlock and relock the sheet. How can I do this?